# ASP Net Core IIS error on any settings. Webconfig AspNetCoreModuleV2 problem?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-config

[image: IIS popup]

I have asp .net core server built with .net 5
IIS has dedicated app pool "ApplicationName" (No Managed Code)
Application is added under Default Web Site and uses it pool.

Whenever I click any option in IIS I got Web config error.

access via browser leads to HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\ApplicationName.Server.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

as soon as i remove

```
<aspNetCore processPath=".\ApplicationName.Server.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

then i can change settings in IIS

I HAVE installed ASP.NET Core 5.0 Runtime (v5.0.17)
I HAVE installed Windows Hosting Bundle v5.0.17
I HAVE installed AspNetCoreModuleV2 in IIS
I HAVE restarted Rewrite module
I HAVE restarted IIS

It seems something is wrong with AspNetCoreModuleV2 but I cannot figured out what exactly is wrong.
I have tried to uninstall bundle and AspNetCoreModuleV2 and reinstall and reenable AspNetCoreModuleV2 but nothing helped.

I have other NON asp net core apps hosted in same IIS and they work just fine.

Any ideas?

Solution* Somehow after installing LATEST Windows Hosting Bundle .NET 8 it started work with .NET 5 core app.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html Run a report and the cause should be clear. BTW, .NET 5 is long dead and you have to upgrade.

Comment: Did the config you have posted is all your web.config settings? Besides, what's the result if you run dotnet --info in cmd?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent Is your application published as cross-platform?